# How can I update the value in FutureProvider with riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a FutureProvider with a List of items. How can I update an item in this list without a refresh the provider?

Comment: FutureProvider does not yet support query mutation; you will need to manage the state yourself, like StateNotifier or Notifier, or use ref.invalidate to refresh the list. https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1660

Answer (score 2):

You should use a StateNotifierProvider for your list like this:

```
final listProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ListItem, dynamic>((ref) {
  return ListItem([]);
});

class ListItem extends StateNotifier<dynamic> {
  ListItem(List<dynamic> items) : super(items);
  void update(dynamic item) {
     // Your update logic. You have access to the use with 'state' variable
  }
}
```

Before that you populate the `listProvider` with your future response. Also you should change the `dynamic` type to your object type on the list

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to use futureProvider to be able to use ref.watch(myFutureProvider).when(data: data, error: error, loading: loading) and update a the state without refreshing and fectching the data again.

Comment: What about using another FutureProvider receiving your update? You await your original provider, but fetch your updated state.

Comment: no he should not as that was not the question. He might use `ref.refresh()` somewhere. This answer is only helpful to a whole different scenario

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data you need from the creation function of the `FutureProvider`. This will be executed on every update of the `otherProvider`. So all you need to do is update this `otherProvider` value and your future will refresh automatically.

```dart
 late final FutureProvider<List<String>> allStrings = FutureProvider((ref) {
      var aNewValue = ref.watch(otherProvider);
      return _externalService.getMyStringsFromSomewhere();
  });
```

Comment: not working for me